# Restrict account administration capabilities to a single domain?

Tags: permissions

We have a couple of sections to our site and want to allow for section owners to do some account maintenance instead of us.  We have these two sections and groups of users and roles separated into two separate domains.  I'm wondering if we can create a role that allows for account maintenance, but only within the domain that it exists?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Local Administrator Role to allow management of accounts within a domain.

> Sitecore local administrators can log in to Sitecore and manage the security applications (including assigning security) within that domain. A local administrator cannot create domains or associate domains to users.

Read more in the [Sitecore Docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html)